# Dimensions of a hybrid clip on cycle fenders

Tags: fenders

I have a Fuji Absolute 1.9D cycle size 23 inch hybrid bicycle.

Would someone please recommend the correct dimensions of a clip on fenders (mudguards) that are both functional and aesthetic? (I personally prefer narrow fenders.)

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: How wide are your tyres? How much space is there between the tyres and the frames.

Answer (score 2):

Hybrids vary a lot. So do tyres and mudguards. It took two attempts to find some to fit my hybrid despite ruining thinner tyres than stock. And they weren't clip on. Your preference for narrow mudguards won't count for much if you're running quite wide tyres. Most road bike mudguards fit up to 25mm tyres. Most mudguards that fit more than that are big enough for up to 40mm (at least). These may then not fit inside your frame without being slightly bent towards the tyre.

I suggest you spend some time with a ruler or callipers at the tricky points.

Comment: The zefal trail mudguards look like they were designed to fit - but they're wide.

Comment: Thank you very much, Chris.The width of the tyre is 32 mm. The fenders do not have to be clip-on. They can be screwed on to the fork under the head tube and to the seat stays under the seat post. Hope I make myself clear

Comment: Too wide is better than too narrow.  Water off the back wheel that misses the guard will hit you in the underside of the leg, which is no fun.

Comment: They're not aesthetic but there are also some cheap plastic clip-on ones on eBay that can be trimmed as required.  I had a set until I changed my rack for one they didn't fit with

Comment: @Criggie absolutely.  Also front wheel and shins/tops of feet